# Maximal Ideal Spaces

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces, ideals, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

**STATEMENT:** Let $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ be the $C^*$-algebra of bounded continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $A$ be the $C^*$-subalgebra of $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ generated by $C_∞(\mathbb{R})$ together with the function $f(t) = e^{it}$. Determine $\hat{A}$, which is the maximal ideal space of $A$

**QUESTION** So in this case I used the fact that $C_\infty$ is an ideal, so it is contained in some maximal ideal. I then let $\phi$ be the associated linear functional on $A$. Since our sub algebra is generated by $C_\infty$ and $f(t)$ we see that $\phi$ is uniquely determined by what $\phi(f(t))$ gets mapped to. Since $f(t)$ is invertible it has to be mapped to a nonzero value. Furthermore, the inequality,
$$|\phi(f(t))|\leq |\phi||f(t)|=1\;\;\;\;\; \text{and}\;\;\;\;\; |\phi(f(t)^{-1})|\leq |\phi||f(t)^{-1}|=1$$

So that $|\phi(f(t))|=1$, so $f(t)$ has to be mapped to some element on the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$. Therefore, we can identify the maximal ideal space with the circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$

My question is that when they say determine the maximal ideal space do they just mean up to homeomorphism? If its not too much of a bother it would be helpful if someone outlines how they would solve such a problem.

Comment: $C_\infty$ denotes the functions vanishing at infinity?

Comment: Yes $C_\infty$ denotes functions vanishing at infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to outline the solution.

**I.** First, we describe the set of characters (continuous nonzero linear multiplicative functionals) $\varphi$ on $A,$ which is the same as $\hat A=\{\ker\varphi\mid\varphi:A\to\mathbb C\ \mbox{is a character}\}.$

As you have mentioned, there is a set of characters $\varphi_z\in\hat A$ which vanish on $C_\infty$ and $\varphi_z(f)=z\in\mathbb T\subseteq\mathbb C.$

If $\varphi$ does not vanish on $C_\infty,$ then $\varphi$ is a character on $C_\infty.$ By the description of the dual of $C_\infty=C_\infty(\mathbb R),$ there is a point $t\in\mathbb R$ such that $\varphi(g)=g(t),\ \forall g\in C_\infty.$ There is a unique extension of $\varphi$ onto $A,$ namely $\varphi(f)=f(t)=e^{it}.$ Indeed, take $g\in C_\infty,\ g(t)\neq 0.$ Then $fg\in C_\infty$ and by multiplicativity of $\varphi$ we have $\varphi(f)=\frac{\varphi(fg)}{\varphi(g)}=\frac{fg(t)}{g(t)}=f(t).$ Since $f$ and $C_\infty$ generate $A,$ we have $\varphi(g)=g(t)$ for all $g\in A.$ Let $\varphi_{t}$ denote the character $\varphi.$

It follows that $\hat A$ is the disjoint union $\{\varphi_z\mid z\in\mathbb T\}\cup\{\varphi_t\mid t\in\mathbb R\}.$

**II.** The (Gelfand-)topology $\tau$ on $\hat A$ is the weakest topology such that all functions $g\in C_\infty$ and $f$ are continuous as functions on $\hat A$. (Then all sums, products and sup-norm-limits are continuous on $\hat A$).

Let $g\in C_\infty.$ Then $g(\varphi_z)=0$ and $g(\varphi_t)=g(t).$ Function $g$ is continuous on $\hat A\Longleftrightarrow\tau$ contains all pre-images $g^{-1}((a,b))\Longleftrightarrow$ $\tau$ contains all sets 
$$
\{\varphi_t\mid t\in(c,d)\}\ \mbox{and all sets}\ \{\varphi_t\mid t\in(c,d)\}\cup\{\varphi_z\mid z\in\mathbb T\}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1).
$$

(The latter are $g$-pre-images of open sets containing $0$).

Function is $f$ continuous on $\hat A\Longleftrightarrow\tau$ contains $f$-pre-images of all open subsets of $\mathbb T\Longleftrightarrow\tau$ contains the unions
$$
\{\varphi_z\mid z=e^{it}, t\in(a,b)\}\cup\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb Z}\{\varphi_t\mid t\in(a+2\pi k,b+2\pi k)\}\ \ \ \ \ \ (2).
$$

The sets of type (1) and (2) generate the topology $\tau.$

The topology $\tau$ has the following properties: $\tau$ restricted onto $\mathbb T\subseteq\hat A$ is the usual (euclidean) topology, $\tau$ restricted onto $\mathbb R\subseteq\hat A$ is the usual topology, $\mathbb T$ is closed in $\hat A$, $\mathbb R$ is open in $\hat A,$ the closure of $\mathbb R$ is the whole $\hat A.$

Looking at the sets of type (2) you can imagine how the neighborhoods of $\varphi_z$ look like. The neighborhoods of $\varphi_t$ are given by the "usual intervals in $\mathbb R.$"

You can also try to imagine $(\hat A,\tau)$ as Tracing mentioned in comments "...$\mathbb R$ being a spiral which wraps around a circle $\mathbb T$..."

Comment: Could you expand your explanation of $\varphi=\varphi_t$ if $\varphi$ doesn't vanish on $C_\infty$.

Comment: @S.S: I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this would mean describe the points of $\hat{A}$ as functionals, and also describe their topology (so, up to homeomorphism if you like).

Note though that you have only described those multiplicative functionals that vanish on $C_{\infty}$; there are lots of other multiplicative functionals that don't vanish on $C_{\infty}$.

Comment: Well the only other ideals I can think of are the $C_\infty+c$ where $c\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Or in other words the functions which tends towards a constant at infinity. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @S.S.   Suppose for a moment $X$ was a compact space, and  consider $C(X)$.  There are lots of maximal ideals in $C(X)$; do you know any of them?  If not, I would begin by studying this example.  (*Gelfand--Naimark theorem* is a key phrase.)  If so, then by analogy you should be able to find lots of maximal ideals in your algebra too.

Comment: Well it seems that some of the other ideals consists of the ideals $I_x=\left\{f\in A:f(x)=0\right\}$

Comment: So it seems that the maximal ideals are simply just $I_x$ and $C_\infty$. The natural identification of the topologies is that the maximal ideals space is merely the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: is my interpretation above correct and have I missed any maximal ideals.

Comment: @S.S.  Suppose that $A$ were generated by $C_{\infty}$ together with the constant function $1$.  Then $C_{\infty}$ would be a maximal ideal, and your description of the maximal ideal space would be correct.  But $A$ is bigger than this, and $C_{\infty}$ is not a maximal ideal, and so the maximal ideal space is not just the one point compactification of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: So I think that the maximal ideals are just simply the ideals that are kernels of the linear functionals I described in my original post, and the ideals $I_x$. These should be it unless I have overlooked something, am I correct? And it seems that the maximal ideal space would then be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{T}\times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @S.S. Yes, those are all the maximal ideals.  But first of all, these give $\mathbb T \coprod \mathbb R$, not $\mathbb T \times \mathbb R$; and you still have to describe the topology.  Here it helps to remember that it has to be compact, so obviously $\mathbb R$ won't be a closed subset!

Comment: The topological space appears to be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{T}^2$ since for every $\phi$ which has kernel containing $C_\infty$ there is a similar character with ideal $I_x$. And if we examine the subbasis there's always two copies of linear functionals which maps $f(t)$ to the same value on the circle group. Am I close, or completely far off course?

Comment: @S.S.  A little of course.  You should be able to check that the topology induced on $\mathbb R$ is just the usual one, for example.

Comment: For the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ we can see that its the usual ones by looking at shifts of the function $e^{-|t|}$.Also by looking at the function $f(t)$ we see that the balls on $\mathbb{T}$ also contains segmented parts of the real line. So it appears that the topology has $R$ dense in it.

Comment: @S.S.  Yes, it does.

Comment: I now see how I should go about approaching this problem, thanks for that, but do you mind writing up a short proof or outline that condenses what we have gone over in the comments. I am still having some trouble finding out the topology, or at least a homeomorphic object that I can visualize.

Comment: My previous comment seems to indicate some frowned upon activity so I will rephrase my request. I am asking if you could condense the comments into a series of steps(hints) into solving this problem for future reference. It would be a big help for me and others in approaching similar problems. Thanks

Comment: @S.S I don't know about "frowned upon activity"; I've just been busy with other things.  If I have time I'll try to write up more.  In the meantime, you may want to look at the wikipedia page on [Stone-Cech compatifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone–Čech_compactification), especially [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone–Čech_compactification#Construction_using_C.2A-algebras).  Your algebra is not the whole ring of bounded continuous functions, and so doesn't see the entire Stone-Cech compactification, just a quotient of it obtained by adding a circle onto $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @S.S As to the topology: think of $\mathbb R$ as being a spiral which wraps around a circle, getting ever closer and closer; its closure will then be the union of $\mathbb R$ and the circle, and will be compact; this is what you maximal ideal spar looks like.

Comment: Thanks tracing for helping me out. I appreciate it.